# Hashing within a class

Tags: python, class, object, hash, set

Im trying to hash an object of a custom class using the

```
hash()
```

function. My code does the following within the class

```
def __hash__(self):
    return hash(tuple(self.somelistattribute))
```

Where the attribute somelistattribute is list of lists such as:

Why do i keep getting an error:

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

How do I fix it?

Answer (score 3):

Because `list` is unhashable, and that includes the sublists.  To convert the sublists, use [map()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map):

```
    return hash(tuple(map(tuple, self.somelistattribute)))
```

Comment: I tried this, I get the same error. I forgot to mention that the it is not a list of lists of integers, but a list os lists of strings. Does that change anything?

Comment: Would you mind giving an example that reproduces the problem?

Comment: You mean the class constructor? or where I'm specifically encountering the problem?

Comment: I mean the list of lists that can't be pickled.  A list of lists of strings when converted to a tuple of tuples of strings doesn't have any lists that can't be pickled.  I'd like an example of your list.

Comment: [["*", "*", "*", "*", "*"],["*", "*", "*", "*", "*"],["*", "*", ".", "*", "*"], ["*", "*", "*", "*", "*"],["*", "*", "*", "*", "*"]]

Comment: I got `-8132435515612606815` as the hash result.  I had no problems.

Comment: To use inline code like I just did, put `\`` around it.

Comment: My hash result is `4422680499992831477`.

Comment: `def __hash__(self):

        return hash(tuple(map(tuple,self._marker)))

Comment: That works just fine for me.  Is `self._marker` too long to show me the whole thing?

Comment: Can i send you a screen shot or something of that sort

Comment: That screenshot would be great.  If you would include the code, the output of `print(repr(self._marker))`, and the full traceback, that would be great.

Comment: the second screenshot is the one causing the error, I'm trying to check a set for the object

Comment: If you are using `__hash__` just for comparisons, you should define `__eq__` instead.

Comment: Ive defined eq too, Im using hashing because i specifically need to use a set for efficiency purposes. the set seen gets larger and larger with each call, going up to 100000 items, so I need hashing specifically for using a set instead of a list

Comment: That image certainly makes it look like it is a problem with the `__hash__` method, but that *should* work.  I can't really tell you anything except make sure that you defined `__hash__` on the right class, and make sure that it has the code that I gave.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the lists *inside of* your outer list. Those aren't hashable, and calling `tuple()` only changes the *outer* list to a tuple.

You can fix this in a few ways, like with `map()`:

```
hash(tuple(map(tuple, list_of_lists)))
```

or with a comprehension:

```
hash(tuple(tuple(x) for x in list_of_lists))
```

Comment: I tried this, it doesn't work and i encounter the same problem

Comment: @SrikanthSrinivas then please [edit] your question to contain code that demonstrates the problem. The code in your question works perfectly fine with the answers you've been given so far.

Comment: @SrikanthSrinivas and that changed nothing; the answers here still work perfectly fine for the example in your question.

Comment: @DanGetz: By the way, the `[edit]` shortcut link is for the post under which it is used.  In this case, your link is for editing your answer.